# Akka fire-forget on remote system delivers not all messages

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-remote-actor

I've got the following scenario:

- Akka Remote System A
- Akka Remote System B

B is a analysis engine, which sends a brunch of fire and forget messages to A. System B stops after it's analysis.

But if B calls after it's analysis `system.shutdown`, not all messages are delivered to A. Is the actor system of B buffering the messages?

How I'm able to ensure that the all B messages are now in A's inbox?
Can I determine, when it's safe for B to disconnect?
How do I properly disconnect B from A?

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: what about using `?` instead of `!` to get responses?

Comment: This is really slow. The architecture should follow a event driven design. The messages are of the nature "this thing happened".

Comment: futures you get can be executed on different dispatcher and update some atomic counter which will indicate if it is allowed to shutdown the system. Where is the slow part or I missed something?

Comment: Don't confuse "slow" with "time passes". Intermachine communication can take on the order of a few milliseconds to occur. The promise of Akka is not that "all your troubles are over" but that you have a way to properly model the communications channels and take corrective actions at all stages. You can disconnect B from A *after* A has received all the messages, for which you will need an acknowledgement process.

Answer (score 1):

You could create several child actors that send the messages and kill themselves as soon as they are done sending their messages. With [supervision](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/general/supervision.html) you could then wait for all child actors to be terminated and after that shutdown the system.
Imo this should be enough for the messages to be sent.